# cassandra.cqlengine.columns.UUID and Django {% url %} tag

Tags: django-models, cassandra, django-urls, datastax-enterprise, datastax-startup

I am running Django together with Cassandra DB. The `cassandra.cqlengine.columns.UUID` variable is translated by the `url` tag in Django template to the form of `UUID('uuid_identifier')`.

The expression `{% url 'myapp' uuid %}` results in url like  `.../UUID('uuid_identifier')`
. This causes problem if you are awaiting `url` in form of  `.../uuid_identifier`.

#### What is the recommended or correct use of cassandra.cqlengine.columns.UUID variables in Django templates?

#### Do I need to write own filter?

Comment: What version of the Cassandra driver are you using?

Comment: @peytoncas: cassandra-driver 1.5.6

Comment: Have you tried casting your uuid to a str before sending it to your Django template? str(uuid)

Comment: @peytoncas I am using DjangoCassandraModel from django_cassandra_engine.models. My intention is to use fields with  UUID type. Maybe there is some possibility to implement a getter for this type of fields. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly you don't have to convert a UUID to pass it in the URL template tag.  As long as the url regex matches for the UUID, you're good to go.  The debug output makes it seem like passing the UUID as an object is not acceptable, however it is.

Example of when the private key is a UUID4:

```
[urls.py]
url(r'^your_page/(?P<pk>[a-f0-9-]+)/$', views.your_page, name='your_page')

[templates/your_page.html]
<a href="{% url 'your_page' your_model.pk %}">Go to your page</a>
```